# Implement a read receipt feature in Firebase group messaging app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'd like to implement a 'Seen' feature in my Firebase group messaging app. Can you kindly advise the best and most efficient approach to take (working code will be appreciated)? For example, the app would show "**Seen by 6**" or "**Seen by 15**" on a group message.

Here's my project: https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/tree/master/android

Here's the MainActivity: https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/codelab/friendlychat/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to add another node in your Firebase database named `seenBy` which must be nested under each `messageId` in `meassage` section. Your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   ---- messages
           |
           ---- messageId1
                   |
                   ---- meessage: "Hello!"
                   |
                   ---- timestamp: 1498472455940
                   |
                   ---- seenBy
                          |
                          ---- userUid1: John
                          |
                          ---- userUid2: Mary
                          |
                          ---- userUid3: George
```

Every time a new user opens a meesage, just add the `uid` and the `name` as explained above.

To implement `Seen by 6` option, it's very easy. You just need to create a `listener` and use `getChildrenCount()` method like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference seenByRef = rootRef.child("messages").child(messageId).child("seenBy");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long seenBy = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        Lod.d("TAG", "Seen by: " + seenBy);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
seenByRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

To know whether a message has been opened or not, you need to add another field to your user section in which you need to add a `boolean` with the default value of `false`. This new section should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   ---- users
       |
       ---- userId1
           |
           ---- meessages
              |
              ---- messageId1: false
              |
              ---- messageId2: false
              |
              ---- messageId3: false
```

When a users opens that message, just set the value of that particular message from `false` to `true`, which means that the particular message has been opened. This is the code:

```
DatabaseReference openedRef = rootRef.child("users").child(userId).child("meessages").child("messageId1");
openedRef.setValue(true);
```

When you create a message, use `push()` method on the reference like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference messageRef = rootRef.child("meessages").push();
String messageKey = messageRef.getKey();
```

Having this key, you can use it in your `DatabaseReference`. In the same way you can use for the userId.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent. But, in the project listed in my question, how would I know that a message has been opened? That's my only issue. Could you please add this point in your answer?

Comment: As you can see, the project uses populateViewHolder() to show messages.

Comment: With your first block of code, I'm getting error: `Cannot resolve symbole 'messageId'` What should I do to solve this?

Comment: The `messageId1` is the id of your message. I assume that every message from your database has an id. So, `messageId1` is the that `unique id` which makes every message different. I have named it `messageId1` generically, you need to use in your code the actual message id.

Comment: That's my question. How can I write the actual message ID?

Comment: Yes, but this won't work if I want to see how many times other people's messages have been seen. That's what I want.

Comment: It will work 100%. That's why i wrote you that code, to see how many peoples have seen a message. Actually it's working in one of my projects.

Comment: Okay, understood. You said "Every time a new user opens a meesage, just add the uid and the name as explained above." I don't know how to do that because in my project it's hard to know when the message has been opened. Please see the project linked in my question and please advise when to add the UID.

Comment: I tried at line 177 of MainActivity (populateViewHolder) but I kept getting nightmare bugs.

Comment: This is what i advised you. How to see when a message is open? You'll know that, when the user clicks on it. To get to uid you can use this code: `FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();` and `String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();`. So get it when the user logs in.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding. The problem is that I don't know how to **detect** a message opening.

Comment: The problem is the detection from the client side. The problem is with my project. Do you understand? :)

Comment: I repeat: I don't know how to **detect** a message opening in order to set the value of that particular message from `false` to `true`

Comment: As i said before, when a user opens(clicks) the chat in which are the messages, or the message it self, then you need to change that value. In order to see when a user has clicked, use `setOnClickListener` or if you are using a `ListView` use `setOnItemClickListener`.

Comment: There are no clicks. Please open up my project in Android Studio. This will clarify the problem.

Comment: Please write me the flow of your app. How can the user reach a message?

Comment: A user sends a message > firebase database receives it > the receiver retrieves this message using `protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder,
                                              FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage, int position)` You'll find this in line 117 of MainActivity

Comment: If the messages are NOT nested in `chat rooms` and the user can see the messages in the moment in which opens the app, than you need to implement that option in the moment in which the user starts the app. Because that moment coresponds with the time when he/she sees the message.

Comment: But sometimes, a message can come *after* the user started the app.

Comment: Than you need to implement `chat rooms`. And every time a user enters a specific `chat room` than all the messages can have the value of true, because the user have seen them. Exactly like Whatsapp.

Comment: I have the same question but in my case i can if the user has seen the message or not but not in real time the user have to restart his activity to see if the message is seen or not  can you please review it here is the link    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61483623/how-to-show-if-a-message-is-seen-or-not-via-using-firebase-real-time-database

Comment: @AlexMamo Is that messageId is the ID that is generated automatically when the message is sent by the user? I am really confused how to get it back the same Id so that I can track the corresponding user for example who sent that message by taking out the user ID field ? Explanation is really good, one confusion still remains.

Comment: @BadriPaudel *Is that messageId is the ID that is generated automatically when the message is sent by the user?* Yes it is. *I am really confused on how to get it back the same Id so that I can track the corresponding user for example who sent that message by taking out the user ID field ?* Store that id in a property of the object. *Explanation is really good* Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it is possible, You can add a child `seen_by` to the message, whenever  user views the message append the viewers userId to the `seen_by` , then by retrieving the `userID` and you can count the number of viewers and also you can see the list of viewed members too. The format should be

```
message:{
    FirebaseKey:{
        message:"hi",
        timestamp:1498472455940,
        seen_by:"abc,def,ghi" //users UID
      }
    }
```