# how to implement message seen feature in Firebase chat app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I'm developing `firebase` chat app.I want to include `seen` feature init just like **whatsapp** . I have  referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614301/implement-a-read-receipt-feature-in-firebase-group-messaging-app) to build database.

I'm using `addChildEventListener` to fetch data from `firebase`.And this is my app [image]  every thing works fine.

I don't know how to achieve this feature because we don't have any control like `click event` on messages.

Thank you in Advance.

`

Comment: What I used to do is to have a field for every message `seen` which is going to be a boolean. This field will change to `true` iff the user asked to see the messages from the firebase database

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming your database is like `messages/{messageId}/seenBy/{uid} -> {name}`.

A straightforward solution would be this one:

In the child event listener callback, while adding the message to your view, check if `messageSnapshot.child('seenBy').child(myUid).exists()`. If it doesn't exist, write your name there like `messageSnapshot.child('seenBy').child(myUid).getRef().set(myName)`.

You would also have to handle "child changed" events, that will fire when users write their names in `seenBy`.