# How to show if a message is seen or not via using Firebase Real time Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show if a message is seen or not in my app which is using Firebase Real time Database.What i am able to till now is update it on on the database if the message is seen or not but i am not able to retrieve that value using listeners in my recyclerview Adaptor .It happens that if the last message is not seen it displays all the previous messages are not seen similarly if the last message is seen it displays all the previous messages are seen.

Database Structure
 [image]

My Code for checking if the message is seen or not

```
     @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Chat chat=mChat.get(position);
        holder.show_message.setText(chat.getMessage());

        if (Key != null) {

            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats").child(ChatKey).child(Key);

            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Chat chat1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                    if (chat1.isIsseen()) {

                        holder.Delivered.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_all_black_24dp);
                    } else {
                        holder.Delivered.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            };
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(eventListener);

        }

        if (imageurl.equals("default")){
            holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.user2);
        } else {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(imageurl).into(holder.profile_image);
        }
}
```

Update

Chat Class

```
    public class Chat {
    private String sender;
    private String receiver;
    private  String message;
    private boolean isseen;
    private long timestamp;
    String MessageId;

    public Chat(String sender, String receiver, String message, boolean isseen, long timestamp) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.message = message;
        this.isseen = isseen;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public Chat() {
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return MessageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        MessageId = messageId;
    }

    public boolean isIsseen() {
        return isseen;
    }

    public void setIsseen(boolean isseen) {
        this.isseen = isseen;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

Update2

isseen Listener

```
private void seenMessage(final String userid){
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats").child(ChatKey);
    // reference.keepSynced(true);
    seenListener=new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                    if (chat.getReceiver().equals(fuser.getUid()) && chat.getSender().equals(userid)) {

                        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("isseen", true);
                        snapshot.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(seenListener);

}
```

Comment: add the database image to your question.

Comment: I have uploaded the Database Structure of chats do I have to upload the all of the DatabaseStructure  @HasanBouTaam

Comment: not in a link. Add the image directly to the question.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam Added the image

Comment: add the `Chat` class also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do this in `onBindViewHolder`**

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Chat chat=mChat.get(position);
    holder.show_message.setText(chat.getMessage());

    boolean isSeen = chat.isIsseen();

    if(isSeen){
    //seen                  
    holder.Delivered.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_all_black_24dp);

    }else{
    //not seen                
    holder.Delivered.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp);


    }


    if (imageurl.equals("default")){
        holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.user2);
    } else {
        Glide.with(mContext).load(imageurl).into(holder.profile_image);
    }

   }
```

**UPDATE:**

**If you want to refresh the recycler view for live updates add this method under the `onBindViewHolder()`:**

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged() {
//refresh
 yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: its updating if the message is seen or not but not in real time i have to restart the activity .Can it be because of how i am updating my isseen because isseen is called on onCreate

Comment: I have added isseen listener should i use it in onStart

Comment: I get an error method does not override from its super class

Comment: You must override the method like you do with `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: Actually the problem is with isseen when i start activity it is set true for the previous message received but while inside the activity the users receive a new messages its set to false until the user who received the message restarts the activity.